# Always returning empty array

Tags: php, arrays, session, array-push

Array always returning empty array in php

trying to make a checkout basket, i tried array_push function in php, but it always returns an empty array.

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
session_start();
$_SESSION['menu']=array();
if(isset($_SESSION['us'])){
    echo "<body>
        <form method='GET'>
        <input type='text' name='item'>
        <button type='submit' name='add'>add</button>
        <button type='submit' name='place'>place</button>
        </form>
       </body>";
    if(isset($_GET['add'])){
    $item = $_GET["item"];
    array_push($_SESSION['menu'], $item);
    }
    if(isset($_GET['place'])){
        print_r($_SESSION['menu']);
    }
}
else{
    echo "you are not logged in";
}
?>
```

Comment: header.php only contains $_SESSION['us'] which stores username

Comment: What does `header.php` contain **exactly**? You are starting the session below the include, so something is definitely not right apart from the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

As while loading page all time you are setting `$_SESSION['menu']` as empty array

```
include 'header.php';

session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['menu']))
    $_SESSION['menu'] = array();

if(isset($_SESSION['us'])){
    echo "<body>
        <form method='GET'>
        <input type='text' name='item'>
        <button type='submit' name='add'>add</button>
        <button type='submit' name='place'>place</button>
        </form>
       </body>";
    if(isset($_GET['add'])){
        $item = $_GET["item"];
        array_push($_SESSION['menu'], $item);
    }

    if(isset($_GET['place'])){
        var_dump($_SESSION['menu']);
    }
} else{
    echo "you are not logged in";
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro, it worked and thanks for making me understand my mistake